# Insert, Sqlite datagrid c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, wpf

Tengo que insertar multiples registos desde un datagrid(66mil aproximadamente) a una base de datos sqlite pero no logro insertar mas de 150 y luego da error, este seria el codigo
QUERY

```
private void Insert_ItemSubGroup_Table()
    {
        if (indice== IndiceFinal)
        {
            // SOLO MENSAJE
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (cnnSQLite.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    cnnSQLite.Open();
                SQLiteCommand command = cnnSQLite.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT  INTO ItemSubGroup_Table(ItemSubGroupKey) " +
                                                    "VALUES('{0}')",
                    ItemSubGroup_Table.ItemSubGroupKey));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnnSQLite.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

DataGrid

```
private void Tables_Container_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
     DataGrid DGV_Tables_Container = (DataGrid)sender;
     DataRowView row_selected = DGV_Tables_Container.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
     if (table.Name == "ItemSubGroup_Table")
        {
            if (row_selected == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            ItemSubGroup_Table.ItemSubGroupKey = row_selected[0].ToString();               
            Colum_0_txt.Text = ItemSubGroup_Table.ItemSubGroupKey;                
        }
        
    indice = Tables_Container.SelectedIndex;
        File_Num_txt.Text = Convert.ToString(indice);
        if (checkBox_Insert_All.IsChecked == true)
        {
            AutomaticInsert2();
        }
        
    }
```

y un contador:

```
private void Count()
    {           
            if (indice == IndiceInicial + 150)
            {
                return;
            }                     
        siguiente = indice + 1;
        File_Num_txt.Text = Convert.ToString(siguiente);
        Tables_Container.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(siguiente);
                
    }
```

....El tema es que me funciona bien hasta los 150 registros(por eso le puse tope), alguna idea?

EDITE el codigo solo para el Ejemplo..
...
...
desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes publicar el error que te da por favor. ¿cómo es invocado el método `Insert_ItemSubGroup_Table()`? mencionas 150 (y más) registros imagino que haces un recorrido del `DataGrid` y lo invocas en cada iteración pero puedes publicar el código por favor.

Comment: En el codigo observo un `if` que evalua un `IndiceFinal` donde se muestra un mensaje relacionado a un maximo de 150, no sera ese codigo el que causa el problema? porque de esa validacion? cual es el mensaje de error que recibes?

Comment: Tambien observo un `catch (Exception)` pero esta vacio, esa es una pesima idea, NUNCA se deja un catch sin hacer nada porque despues tienes problemas y no te enteras que sucede, quita ese try..catch o sino implementa un login o mensaje del exception que recibes

Comment: Edite el codigo para el ejemplo, se que tendria que hacer un forech pero no encontre un ejemplo que me ayude